# Spark - write to parquet never finish

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, parquet

I have some strange issue with my spark on emr.
when I run spark job and save dataframe to CSV the job finish successfully , but when I try to save to parquet, the Spark application never finish , but i see that all internal tasks are finished.
also I can see that all parquet files created in relevant partitions

I run on EMR : emr-5.13.0
and spark 2.3.0
    scala 2.11

the write to parquet is :

```scala
 newDf.coalesce(partitions)
      .write.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
      .partitionBy("key1", "key2")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .parquet(destination)
```

Comment: Check the maximum length on both of those columns, it could be that one of your rows is corrupted.

Comment: thanks, @afeldman, check it.. all files have some length and columns..  so it's not the problem :(